# Why std::istringstream generates wrong results without raising the failbit flag?

Tags: c++, string, stream, floating-point, qnx

When I convert a `string` that contains `long double` to `float` or `double`, `std::istringstream` doesn't raise the failbit flag in **QNX**.

The following is a demonstration code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main(){
    const long double originaldNumber = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max() / 2;
    float floatNumber;
    std::string numberString = std::to_string(originaldNumber);

    //From string to long double
    std::istringstream iss(numberString);
    iss >> floatNumber;

    if (iss.fail())
        std::cout<< "iss failed \n";

    std::cout<< std::setprecision(30) << originaldNumber << "\n";
    std::cout<< std::setprecision(30) << floatNumber << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output in linux is:

```
 iss failed 
 5.94865747678615882510631926515e+4931
 3.40282346638528859811704183485e+38
```

The output in QNX is:

```
5.94865747678615882510631e+4931
inf
```

QNX version: `7.0.3 2018/09/18-00:28:50EDT x86pc x86_64`.
Toolchain: `gcc_ntox86_64`

Comment: Please specify what the toolchain is, including version.

Comment: I use this: QCC -V5.4.0,gcc_ntox86_64 main.cpp -o qnxTest -std=gnu++14.  My version: QNX localhost 7.0.3 2018/09/18-00:28:50EDT x86pc x86_64

Answer (score 2):

According to cppreference.com, here is what happen:

#### [`std::istringstream::operator<<(float&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> (5) extracts a floating point value by calling `std::num_get::get()`

#### [`std::num_get::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get)

> ## Stage 3: conversion and storage
>
> The input is parsed as if by `std::strtof`
>
> In any case, if the conversion function fails `std::ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`.

#### [`std::strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)

> ## Return value
>
> Floating point value corresponding to the contents of str on success. If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, range error occurs and `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF` or `HUGE_VALL` is returned. If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned and `*str_end` is set to `str`.

#### [`HUGE_VALF`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/HUGE_VAL)

> `HUGE_VALF`    Expands to positive float expression that indicates overflow

---

In your case, it is clear that `std::strtof` with `5.94...e+4931` will overflow a `float`, it should return `HUGE_VALF`, which is an error value for this function. Under linux:

```
float const have_overflown = std::strtof("1e307", nullptr);
std::cout << "equals HUGE_VALF: " << std::boolalpha
          << (have_overflown == HUGE_VALF) << '\n';     // true
std::cout << "string repr: " << have_overflown << '\n'; // inf
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5ab906f72610c72)

Since `std::strtof` effectively returns `HUGE_VALF` for overflowing values, the failbit of a stream calling it *should* be set, as mandated in the spec of `std::istringstream::operator<<(float&)`.

QNX fails this requirement. You could try and check where in the chain it fails.

---

According to [QNX doc on `strtof`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/s/strtod.html):

> If the correct value would cause overflow, plus or minus HUGE_VAL is returned according to the sign, and errno is set to ERANGE.

You could check `errno` against `ERANGE` in addition to checking the stream failbit:

```
errno = 0;
iss >> floatNumber;
if (iss.fail() || errno == ERANGE) {
    // fail
}
```

---

Finally, if your implementation fails to conform to its own documentation as you say id does in the comment section, you could check `floatNumber` against `HUGE_VALF` to detect overflows.

Comment: thanks for the hint. For unknown reasons `errno` is not changed. In QNX `errno = 0`, in Linux `errno=34`

Comment: Yes I will do. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @H.Ilyas FYI It's kind of customary on SO to add a link to the bug report if it is publicly visible. You can write your own answer to the question and update it if it is solved one day.